# Was the filament structure of the universe due to the same process as in the continuity equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology, universe

In [this long Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/DrPhiltill/status/1097707582041608192?s=19), Dr Phil Metzger suggests that the large-scale filament structure of the universe is due to the same process that determines the continuity equation.

The entire tweet thread is about his observations of a water fountain, where he notices the water following the continuity equation:

$$A \propto \frac{1}{v}$$

Where, since the water accelerates due to gravity, the cross-sectional area of the water decreases until eventually, the area is so small that surface tension can no longer maintain the sheet, and the water separates into filaments.

Later in the thread, he suggests that the same thing happened in the early universe: since the universe was expanding, eventually the uniform fluid which filled the universe separated into filaments, just as is observed in simulations and in galaxy distributions.

However, I was under the impression that was filament nature was due to anisotropies in the density of the early universe caused by quantum fluctuations. The anisotropies were then amplified into the filaments that we observe by gravitational collapse.

So, is it true that the same process as in the continuity equation affected the filament structure of the universe?

Comment: Equation cannot affect the Universe. You confuse model and reality. The question of the mechanism of formation of the structure of the Universe can be considered in the framework of the hydrodynamic model.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Ah yes, perhaps I worded it wrongly

Comment: This is a question about the mechanism of occurrence of singularities. The continuity equation itself does not describe the occurrence of singularities. But together with the Navier-Stokes  equation describes blowup solutions with the formation of a singularity for a finite time.